# Extreme high voltage path of least resistance changes?

Tags: electricity, plasma-physics

In this video, there is an extremely high voltage being sent through a blank breadboard. The arcs go through different, seemingly random new paths. What causes this? How could you determine what the next path would be?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MISuVItKgo
[image]

Comment: I'm eagerly awaiting the answer.  I've had questions about lightning traveling through air for a long time.

Comment: @user3533030 my suspicion is that heating the air or adding plasma increases the resistance of the path so it must choose another

Answer (score 2):

> Why does electricity travel through the air through different paths?

In general, an arc is heating the air along its path, which causes the air to expand and rise, which, in turn, affects the path of the arc, causing it to wander. As an example, you can observe a constantly moving discharge path of an arc through an open air gap around [$19$ seconds](https://youtu.be/5MISuVItKgo?t=19) into the video.

When the open air gap between the electrodes is replaced by a breadboard, the paths along x and y, as discussed in the video, become more favorable than other random paths, which explains a general "square" pattern, but, since the air is still constantly moving, at any given time, some "square" paths are more favorable than others.

Perhaps, this would not be the case for a DC arc, which, once established, would be less likely to drastically change its path.

Comment: The question isn't about why they travel across the square paths, the question is why does the path of least resistance keep changing?

Comment: @10Replies I see it now. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

In electric discharges, there is a randomness. There is the theory of [diffusion-limited aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation) where random walks of ions and molecules may explain lightning, Lichtenberg figures, chemical trees, snowflakes, etc. In this case, ionizing radiation may play a role, as for example in this [muon spark chamber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpW08xV3RI8).

In this systen, the square pattern is responsible for the directions. And maybe a discharge somehow erases or burns away its own path, so that it does not become permanent.